# Angular - how to pass ng-model from ng-repeat to a function and to scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have the following code:

```
<form ng-submit="addRow($index)">
    <input type="text" ng-repeat="column in table.columns" ng-model="column">
    <input type="submit" value="add row">
</form>
```

Live code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/muehvxx1/

What I'm trying to do is that whenever you click on the "Add Row" button, a new object is added to the scope (to the form's parent object) passing all values from the form's fields.

So far you can add an object to the correct parent (that works), but it doesn't pass the fields' values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/9g8vpnaa/

HTML: Form

```
<form ng-submit="addRow(table)">
  <input type="text" ng-repeat="column in table.columns" ng-model="table.newItem[column]">
  <input type="submit" value="add row">
</form>
```

JS: addRow()

```
$scope.addRow = function(table){
  table.items.push(table.newItem);
  table.newItem = {};
};
```

Answer (score 2):

What I was add and additional object newRow to all your tables

```
    $scope.tables = [
        {name: 'tweets',
        columns: ['id', 'message', 'user'],
        items: [
            {id: 1, message: 'hello', user: 'mike'},
            {id: 2, message: 'hi', user: 'bob'},
            {id: 3, message: 'whatup', user: 'bob'}
        ],
         newRow :{}
        },
        {name: 'users',
        columns: ['id', 'username'],
        items: [
            {id: 1, username: 'mike'},
            {id: 2, username: 'bob'}
        ],
         newRow :{}
        }
    ];
```

I then use that object to bind to the inputs

```
<form ng-submit="addRow(table)">
    <input type="text" ng-repeat="column in table.columns" ng-model="table.newRow[column]" />
    <input type="submit" value="add row" />
</form>
```

Then you just have to add that object to the items when the user clicks "Add Row"

```
    $scope.addRow = function(table){
        console.log($scope.id);
        table.items.push(table.newRow);
    };
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enlightenmedia/muehvxx1/1/)

Comment: I like the way you think ;)

Comment: One of us must have been thinking too loudly :)

Comment: Thanks, but that only works the first time you submit. After that, every time you change the values inside the "input" fields they change the values of the already existing object, which shouldn't happen.

Comment: rob's answer solves that by creating a new newItem after adding